# Can someone help or point me out to C++ source code for a two body orbit simulation using symplectic integration?

Tags: computational-physics, c++, simulation

I've professional experience with physics simulations and C++ programming, although
I don't have specific experience with astrophysics simulations.

I'm trying to build a two-body evolving system myself, but I'm struggling with obtaining even the simplest stable orbit (more than just a few revolutions).

Therefore I'm looking for some advice or ideally some source code project as reference.

I'm starting from random parameters, as I do not want to force anything in place.
I've used Runge-Kutta from boost as it was suggested to me, but now I doubt that's enough.
Planets tends to crash into each other or separate immediately.
I've tried also to limit the initial parameters in some sensible range.

Best result I've obtained was a few revolutions, not stable at all (also in terms of trajectories).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me, this sounds like an issue in the implementation of the right-hand side of ODE or a bad selection of initial conditions.  While a symplectic method is a good choice, its benefits will likely only be apparent for long-term integration.  Over just a few orbits, the difference between a symplectic and non-symplectic integrator should be negligible.

Comment: Did you tried with a simpler ODE first? A pendulum, for example.

Comment: One also needs to avoid singular situations, as for close encounters of two planets the relative velocity can get so high that the sampling frequency of the fixed-step integration is too low, radically increasing the error in the energy. One could use adaptive-step methods until such a situation is resolved and then continue with the symplectic method.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66893929/velocity-verlet-algorithm, and other topics from the tag "orbital-mechanics", and also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1392051/numerical-solution-to-a-system-of-second-order, but math.SE has less on the Verlet method under the tag "celestial-mechanics"

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes I've tried with a simple pendulum and also done some numerical test after I started to wonder why wasn't working for this other "simple" case.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comments guys, very appreciated and I'm looking into what you have said. 
Anyway, some of you mentioned a bad selection of initial conditions or some extreme condition overall, I agree that, it may be actually the case indeed. 
Shouldn't be possible, under a sufficient number of iterations (even in the order of millions or hundreds) to obtain a stable system from random initial conditions? Because I don't want to drop that aspect.

Comment: I couldn't edit my last comment, just to clarify a mistake: by iterations I meant restarts, as in restarting a new fresh instance with new random parameters. Just in case it wasn't clear.

Comment: You could test the 3-body configuration from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66711435, as it is shown, the solution is periodic within the integration accuracy. As there are many close passes, this will stress a fixed-step solver.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks, anyway the link about the 3-body problem is wrong I think, it points to a search algorithm problem. I'll try to find it out by myself, but if you happen to have the correct one, could you link it again please?

Comment: Why did someone downvoted my question? What's wrong with it? Please at least let me understand.

Comment: The program that generates the array to search in is a 3-body simulation, the initial data is easy to find. The previous question of that OP has plots of a similar 3-body problem. /// (Your problem description is not very reproducible, you could add code or an algorithm description along with a selection of initial configurations that illustrate your observations.)

Comment: Have you looked at implementations that can doubtlessly be found on the internet? For example using one of the high-quality variable timestep implementations out there?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I didn't notice initially, I've just read the title and I thought was a link issue as I was into something else, thanks and sorry about that.
What code or description can I add specifically? I think the problem is about the random initial conditions anyway, because it works if I set the some initial values for the bodies that I took from another project. But my point is to see it happening starting from chaotic conditions.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I didn't find any implementation unfortunately. I found implementations that start with optimal initial values, from which I also learn something (like Runge-Kutta may be better or any symplectic integrator for what I understood, so I did), but no example analogue to mine, as I want it to start from random conditions, and if it fails to converge it can restart (I do it in multiple instances as well). Perhaps I didn't look for the correct terms. Could you point me out to some of these resources please?

Comment: @Simo LMGTFY: https://www.google.com/search?q=two+body+integration+code+example&sxsrf=ALeKk00tKKKdygBCXe32xri7bOi0Vqo-aw%3A1628567811504&ei=A_kRYeenHsvG-gTVyJHgDA&oq=two+body+integration+code+example&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKsCOgcIABBHELADOgcIIRAKEKsCSgQIQRgAUJaBAVjIhQFgu4cBaAFwAngAgAHRAYgBlgiSAQUwLjUuMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwintZbvx6XyAhVLo54KHVVkBMwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I don't understand why you should go around suggesting to google, that's not what I usually do with my peers when they ask for help, sounds pretty arrogant. Also I don't know if you have checked the results of the google search you propose, because if you did and you've understood my problem, you'll immediately notice that the whole first page of results (and the following) are not related to my specific problem, all these simulations/articles assume/start with fixed initial values, something that I've specified it's already working for me as well. Thanks anyway.

Comment: How are your random initial conditions distributed? Do you normalize to a barycentric frame so that the center-of-mass stays at the origin? In general you will only get stable simulations for circular orbits or small eccentricities. With raising eccentricity the velocity at the pericenter will grow rapidly, requiring very small time steps.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes I'm normalizing it. For the time step, I hope mine is small enough (~0.5 ms, fixed), I cannot make it run faster than this. Perhaps my problem has exactly to do with the shape/speed of the initial possible orbit (given the random conditions). I've finally found an interesting paper, that is close enough, as they run a sub-experiment with random conditions as well. I'm giving it a try. Thanks again for your hints, definitely helped me reasoning from more perspectives.

Comment: @Simo, I think that it might help to reword the question to emphasize that what you want to achieve is to get periodic solutions from random initial conditions (that's what I understand from your comments). Also, if that's the case it seems to be a question more related to the physics/math of the problem than the computational component.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot claim very deep computational expertise, so in case it might help you, I can just post some code that contains two versions of a fixed-step straight-forward symplectic algorithms (leap-frog / Verlet's type). I however am not so proficient in C++, so I can offer a python version, so maybe you can translate it into C++. On the bright side, the python is more transparent in terms of methodological ideas and organization, so that could be beneficial. The code also does not feature the realistic constants, but scaled versions.

Also, the code is set up to two mass-points in a plane, because you specified that you want to start with a two-body simulation. I hope that's ok to get you started.

````py
'''
Two body leap-forg algorithm simulation
'''

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

'''
Calculation of the gravitational acceleration
r is a 2 x 2 matrix, each row is the position of one of the two mass-points
'''     

def g_accel(r, mass1, mass2):
    r_12 = r[1,:] - r[0,:]
    g_force = mass1 * mass2 * r_12 / np.linalg.norm( r_12 )**3 
    return np.array([g_force / mass1, - g_force / mass2]) 


'''
propagation/numerical integration using leap-from / verlet's type time-reversible symplectic algorithm of convergence rate dt**2 
'''

def propagate_system(r1_in, r2_in, v1_in, v2_in, mass1, mass2, n_steps, dt):
    r = np.empty((n_steps, 2, 2),dtype=float)
    v = np.empty((n_steps, 2, 2),dtype=float)
    r[0,0,:] = r1_in
    r[0,1,:] = r2_in
    v[0,0,:] = v1_in
    v[0,1,:] = v2_in
    for n in range(n_steps-1):
        r[n+1,:,:] = r[n,:,:]  +  dt * v[n,:,:] / 2
        v[n+1,:,:] = v[n,:,:]  +  dt * g_accel(r[n+1,:], mass1, mass2)
        r[n+1,:,:] = r[n+1,:,:] + dt * v[n+1,:,:] / 2
    return r, v

'''
another propagation/numerical integration using leap-from / verlet's type time-reversible symplectic algorithm of convergence rate dt**4 
'''
def propagate_system_1(r1_in, r2_in, v1_in, v2_in, mass1, mass2, n_steps, dt):
    w0 = pow(2, 1/3)
    w1 = 1 / (2 - w0)
    w0 = - w0*w1
    c = np.array([w1, w0+w1 , w0+w1, w1]) / 2
    d = np.array([w1, w0, w1])
    r = np.empty((n_steps, 2, 2),dtype=float)
    v = np.empty((n_steps, 2, 2),dtype=float)
    r[0,0,:] = r1_in
    r[0,1,:] = r2_in
    v[0,0,:] = v1_in
    v[0,1,:] = v2_in
    for n in range(n_steps-1):
        r[n+1,:,:] = r[n,:,:]
        v[n+1,:,:] = v[n,:,:]
        for i in range(3):
            r[n+1,:,:] = r[n+1,:,:] +  c[i]*dt * v[n+1,:,:]
            v[n+1,:,:] = v[n+1,:,:] +  d[i]*dt * g_accel(r[n+1,:,:], mass1, mass2)
        r[n+1,:,:] = r[n+1,:,:] +  c[3]*dt * v[n+1,:,:]
    return r, v


'''
Test simulation:
Initial conditions:
'''
mass1 = 2 
mass2 = 1
initial_position1 = np.array([-1,0]) 
initial_position2 = np.array([1.3,0])
initial_velocity1 = np.array([0, 0.5])

initial_velocity2 = - mass1 * initial_velocity1 / mass2 

'''
Integration parameters:
'''
t_step = 0.05
N = 20000

'''
System time-propagation (numerical integration):
'''
r, v = propagate_system_1(initial_position1, 
                        initial_position2, 
                        initial_velocity1,
                        initial_velocity2, 
                        mass1, mass2, 
                        N, t_step)


'''
reducing the frequency of time-measurements for faster simulation speed 
'''
r = r[np.arange(1, N, 10), :, :]

'''
animation plot of time-evolution:
'''
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_aspect('equal')

ax.set_xlim(-12, 12)
ax.set_ylim(-12, 12)
line = np.empty(2, dtype=type(ax.plot(r[0, 0, 0], r[0, 0, 1])))
for point in range(2):
    line[point], = ax.plot( r[0, point, 0],  r[0, point, 1] )

def animate(i):
    '''
    update plot
    '''
    for p in range(2):
        line[p].set_xdata(r[0:i, p, 0])
        line[p].set_ydata(r[0:i, p, 1])
    return line

intervals = 50
frames = N
frames = int(frames)

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames, interval=intervals)
plt.show()
```
````